# How to access AppCompatActivity from native module?

Tags: react-native

When I want to create a native bridge for a library, I realize that it need an AppCompatActivity instance as a parameter.
I've spent few hours to find a method that can return an AppCompatActivity instance, but I can't find anything, yet.

P.S. there is getCurrentActivity method, but it return Activity instance, instead of AppCompatActivity

Comment: Have you found solution?